# Removing rows in Pandas based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, I have a dataframe with ZipCode, Age, and a bunch of columns that should all have values 1 or 0, ie:

```
ZipCode Age A B C D

12345   21  0 1 1 1
12345   22  1 0 1 4
23456   45  1 0 1 1
23456   21  3 1 0 0
```

I want to delete all rows in which 0 or 1 doesn't appear in columns A,B,C, or D as a way to clean up the data.  In this case, I would remove the 2nd and 4th row because 4 appears in column D in row 2 and 3 appears in column A in row 4.  I want to do this even if I have 100 columns to check such that I don't have to look up every column one by one in my conditional statement.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to test for membership and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to test if all row values are `True` and use this boolean mask to filter the df:

```
In [12]:
df[df.ix[:,'A':].isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]

Out[12]:
   ZipCode  Age  A  B  C  D
0    12345   21  0  1  1  1
2    23456   45  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can opt for a vectorized solution:

```
In [64]: df[df[['A','B','C','D']].isin([0,1]).sum(axis=1)==4]

Out[64]:
   ZipCode  Age  A  B  C  D
0    12345   21  0  1  1  1
2    23456   45  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Other two solutions works well but if you interested in speed you should look at numpy [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) function:

```
data=df.loc[:, 'A':]

In [72]:  df[np.in1d(data.values,[0,1]).reshape(data.shape).all(axis=1)]
Out[72]:
   ZipCode  Age  A  B  C  D
0    12345   21  0  1  1  1
2    23456   45  1  0  1  1
```

**Timing**:

```
In [73]: %timeit data=df.loc[:, 'A':]; df[np.in1d(data.values,[0,1]).reshape(data.shape).all(axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 558 us per loop

In [74]: %timeit df[df.ix[:,'A':].isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 843 us per loop

In [75]: %timeit df[df[['A','B','C','D']].isin([0,1]).sum(axis=1)==4]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```